# I can't find the syntax error in mysql command

Tags: mysql, database

```
CREATE TABLE `üyeler` (
    `id` bigint NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `ad` tinytext NOT NULL,
    `soyad` tinytext NOT NULL,
    `KN` tinytext(11) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    `Eposta` tinytext(50) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    `Telefon` tinytext(11) UNIQUE,
    `şifre` tinytext NOT NULL,
    `favori` bigint NOT NULL,
    `yetki` BOOLEAN NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
```

i use phpmyadmin to create the table. I tried everythin but i can't create the table it says theres a syntax error in it

Comment: `tinytext(11)` should just be `tinytext`. You don't specify a length for text datatypes.

Comment: For such short strings, you should probably use `VARCHAR` anyway. So `tinytext(11)` should be `varchar(11)`

Answer (score 0):

using `varchar` instead of `tinytext` worked!